# Access S3 bucket via Interface Endpoint in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Trying to use the new S3 VPC **Interface** Endpoints to access buckets from on-prem (or VPN).

Use case is I was hoping to use S3 for web assets for internal web apps - something we have not been able to do over Gateway Endpoints without using a proxy (extra maintenance) or Public VIF (routing complexity on-prem).

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#accessing-bucket-and-aps-from-interface-endpoints) show how to access using CLI or SDK's and I have that working. However it's not clear what hostname to use to access via a browser, or if this is even possible.

It looks like the hostname should be:

bucketname.vpce-1a2b3c4d-5e6f.s3.ap-southeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com

But the certificate on s3 is for *.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com so that's not going to work.

Does anyone have this working, or can confirm that it isn't possible? If it's not that's going to be very disappointing.

Comment: What do you mean "through the browser"? S3 console?

Comment: As in the use case I mentioned - css and js scripts in s3 are included in web pages accessed via a browser. A very common use case for public web sites, but it seems difficult to achieve internally

Comment: Even we are stuck in a similar use case. Really need a solution to access S3 buckets via interface endpoints from the on-prem server through a VPN connection.